# Excel can't locate files after saving with new name

Tags: excel, vba, file, directory

I wrote code to copy file address then modify the week number to match the user entry.

It was working but when I tried to get last week results, Excel couldn't find the folder:

In cells text looks like this :

```
=SOMME('\\Backup\Opérations\Coaticook\Production\TRG\TRG Edges\TRG Edge 4\Edge 4 2020\[TRG Edge 4 sem 28.xlsx]Vendredi jour:Lundi jour'!$Q$3:$R$4)
```

and only 28 changes to 29.

Windows that pop for every entry
[image]

Files are located on a server.

Is it a server access issue or related to my Excel settings?

Comment: What happens if you map the Server location as a drive letter and use that in the path to the file? It looks like it cannot find that Server. Also, where does VBA come in? This looks like a worksheet formula.

Comment: Teylyn, my VBA code copies and paste that line and then changes the week number (which makes it now link with the file right underneath it in the same folder). When i do copie and paste then find and replace manualy i dont get the same problem weirdly.

Comment: @TinMan Isn't `SOMME` just the French language version of the English `SUM`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Of course, I'm a big dummy.

Comment: @TinMan you're not the only big dummy, last week (29) was the first to include macro... so hes now .xlsm instead of .xlsx which was the source of the mapping problem ^^',solved, thx a lot guys!

Comment: @Jérôme That's good to hear!  You should post and accept an answer, so as to, close the question.  Cheers!

Comment: @TinMan can only accept my own aswer tomorrow, il sure do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to look at the file format(extension), .xlsm and .xlsx can vary if you include macro in your file. That small detail changes the name and makes excel unable to find the file.